# Is there a python module that can draw multiple one pixel wide points at once?

Tags: python, graphics

I am making a program that draws the Mandelbrot set with graphics.py. I've encountered several issues. For example, every point is 2 pixels wide, making it 4 pixels in total. Also, I would like to be able to draw all of the points at once, which I think graphics.py doesn't allow. Is there a module that allows for that?

code for plotting a point:

```
division = 100
imsize = 2 * division
resize = 3 * division
def spawnplane():
    global plane
    plane = GraphWin("Mandelbrot set", resize, imsize)
    plane.setBackground(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
def spawnaxes():
    imaxis = Line(Point(2 * division, imsize), Point(2 * division, 0))
    reaxis = Line(Point(0, imsize / 2), Point(resize, imsize / 2))
    imaxis.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    reaxis.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    imaxis.draw(plane)
    reaxis.draw(plane)
    ticky = Line(Point(division, imsize / 2 - imsize / 20), Point(division, imsize / 2 + imsize / 20))
    ticky.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    ticky.draw(plane)
def plot(z, color):
    pt = Point((2 + z.real) * division, (1 - z.imag) * division)
    pt.setFill(color)
    pt.draw(plane)
```

Comment: maybe use `numpy.array` and convert to image or display it with `matplotlib` or `cv2` - but `matplotlib` or `cv2` will not work with `graphics.py`.

Comment: BTW: if every point is 2 pixel wide then maybe you use wrong width - maybe you should use `width-1`

Comment: @furas How can you change the width?

Comment: if you want help with `graphics.py` then you should show your code. I don't know how you draw pixels. As I know `graphics.py` is based on `tkinter` which use `rectangle` to draw pixel and it uses `(x,y, width, height)`

Comment: I can't run your code but when I use `pt.draw(plane)` or `plane.plotPixel(x, y, color)` then I always get pixel with size `1x1`. Maybe your problem is in different place - create code which draw only single pixel to see if it really creates pixel bigger then `1x1` . OR maybe it is problem only on your system. I tested on Linux Mint.

Comment: I made screenshot and resize it and you are right `pt.draw(plane)` creates pixel `2x2` but `plane.plotPixel(x, y, color)` create `1x1`

Comment: Asking for recommendations of other libraries is off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [source code](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Zelle%27s_Graphics.py_for_Python_3) and it seems it uses `create_rectangle()` (on `Canvas` in `tkinter`) which has border and this border adds extra 1 pixel and it create point `2x2`. You can't change it even with `pt.setWidth(0)`

[image]

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin()

win.autoflush = False

for x in range(10, 200, 10):
    for y in range(10, 200, 10):
        pt = Point(x, y)
        pt.draw(win)
        
win.autoflush = True
#win.update()

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

But there is `win.plotPixel(x, y, color)` which uses `create_line()` and it creates point `1x1`

[image]

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin()

win.autoflush = False

for x in range(10, 200, 10):
    for y in range(10, 200, 10):
        win.plotPixel(x, y) # plotPixel(x, y, color)
        
win.autoflush = True
#win.update()

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

**BTW:** I use `win.autoflush = False` to redraw window after drawing all pixel. Normally it redraws window after every pixel.